# How to update running balance in one shot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, running-balance

I have a temp table, let's call it #invoices, defined as

```
create table (id int identity(1, 1), billed money, credited money, balance money)
```

i have the following data in it

```
Billed   Credited
140.00   
20.00
          60.00
          20.00
         -20.00
```

I would like to update the **balance** column with the running balance. so that the Balance column is updated properly.  Balance is basically, Billed - Credited, but has to take into the account the previous row.

So in my example, the Balance will be so:

```
Billed   Credited  Balance
140.00              140.00
20.00               160.00
          60.00     100.00
          20.00      80.00
         -20.00    -100.00
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through the rows and keeping the running balance?  Basically I am looking to update the Balance column in a set-based way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *are* set-based ways to calculate running totals in SQL Server, however in the current versions of SQL Server a cursor-based solution is often quicker.

Adam Machanic wrote a great article on it [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/running-sums-redux.aspx).

Comment: Actually the solution i am looking for is in the link you provided - 1st comment by Dennis Allen.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is triggers. I use them, and it works beautifully. I don't have exactly your setup (it's slightly strange, if I may say), but in general, they are the correct approach here. You will need to be mindful of ordering, but other than that, it should be fine.

Comment: Note to people reading: unless someone provides a good reason for this downvote, it's important to note that I'm not wrong - Triggers are far better than cursors for this purpose, and maintaining a balance per-transaction-entry is a little strange.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but your approach is wrong.  Note that the table is temporary.  Why would I do a behind the scenes thing with the triggers when one can happily do it in a script.

Comment: I didn't notice it was temp; you do it with triggers so you always have it up to date. Then you when you want to run a query over a given range, you just do that (cause you have historical data). Your approach makes it difficult to, say, insert a new row (it'd for a total recalculation) at given point.